# Firebase rule - how to restrict value to boolean?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a data structure like this to look up which can/cannot be accessed by public users. I want to add a validation rule so that the value can only be boolean true/false.

```
root {
    Accessibility {
        "ID-123": true,
        "ID-234": false,
        "ID-345": true,
        "ID-456": true,
        "ID-567": false,
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

But I always get a write denied error when I try to write something to Accessibility using the simulator, for example { "TEST": true }. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "rules": {
        "Accessibility": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth != null",
            ".validate": "newData.val() == true || newData.val() == false"
        },
    ....
    ....
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the rules you shared it is applying the rules to the top level of Accessibility and not its keys meaning the new data includes the keys and its value e.g. `ID-123: true` below I restructured it to look at the id and makes use of the `.isBoolean()` function.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Accessibility": {
        ".read": true,
        "$id" : {
          ".write": true,
          ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()",
        }
    },
  }
}
```

and then in the client sdk do your update/set on `/Accessibility/ID-123` with a value of `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ***isBoolean()***?

From the documentation it says:

> Returns true if this RuleDataSnapshot contains a boolean value. Return
>   Value: Boolean - true if the data is a Boolean; else false.

```
".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
```

Comment: Yes, I tried newData.isBoolean(), but I get the same error. I believe newData would be { "TEST": true } which is never boolean. That's why I tried newData.val().